# allias for properties with signalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm looking for a class-propery attribute that'll make the property name different when serialized to client.
exactly like [DataMember(Name="newName")] works with Json on a regular webApi - it doesnt seem to be working with signalR.

Comment: Have you tried using [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) attribute (or [JsonPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1) if you are using .NET Core >=3.0 and `System.Text.Json`)?

Comment: that worked! thanks! 
@GuruStron

Comment: Added as an answer then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark properties with [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) attribute (or [JsonPropertyName](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) if you are using .NET Core >=3.0 and `System.Text.Json`).